# What is different between this when we navigate one view controller to another

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

What is the difference between this first call:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AFVC") as! AddFileViewController
self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and this second:

```
let dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DBVC") as! DashboardViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first usage will present the new view controller. This presentation normally slides the new controller up from the bottom. If you want to go back, you need to create a button or something similar to dismiss it.

The second usage will use the navigation controller to display (via push which normally slides in from the right) the new view controller. You will automatically get a "< Back" button in the navigation bar. But this will only work if the calling view controller is already embedded in a navigation controller, otherwise `self.navigationController` is `nil`.